# Comments cannot be flagged on mobile

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, comment-flags, mobile-web

When browsing on mobile (Chrome, Android), there are no comment flag buttons.

[image: comments screenshot]

If I use the "Desktop site" browser option, the flag button appears next to the upvote button.

Comment: After 5 years I guess this is by-design?

Comment: More like known-shortcoming I guess (unfortunately we don't have that tag). You might want to leave your question around as an indicator people are still running into it.